# Replicating Excel function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel function as follows-

```
IF(B3="","",IF(AND(G3="NA",F3="Qualified"),"New to Qualified",
IF(AND(G3="NA",F3<>"Qualified"),CONCATENATE("New to Qualified and ",F3),
IF(AND(G3<>"NA",F3="Qualified"),IF(H3<>G3,"TCV Change","Same"),
IF(AND(G3<>"NA",F3<>"Qualified"),IF(H3="NA","TCV Change",IF(H3<>G3,CONCATENATE("TCV Change and ",F3),F3)))))))
```

I am trying to replicate the same in VBA as-

```
Sub CC()

Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String

str1 = "New to Qualified and" & Range("F3:F100")
str2 = "TCV Change and" & Range("F3:F100")


Range("J3:J100").Value = IIf(Application.WorksheetFunction.And(Range("G3:G100") = "NA", Range("F3:F100") = "Qualified"), "New to Qualified", _
IIf(Application.WorksheetFunction.And(Range("G3:G100") = "NA", Range("F3:F100") <> "Qualified"), str1, _
IIf(Application.WorksheetFunction.And(Range("G3:G100") <> "NA", Range("F3:F100") = "Qualified"), IIf(Range("H3:H100") <> Range("G3:G100"), "TCV Change", "Same"), _
IIf(Application.WorksheetFunction.And(Range("G3:G100") <> "NA", Range("F3:F100") <> "Qualified"), IIf(Range("H3:H100") = "NA", "TCV Change", IIf(Range("H3:H100") <> Range("G3:G100"), str2, Range("F3:F100")))))))


End Sub
```

However I'm getting an error on the last line- "Compile Error- Argument not optional"

Please help with the same.

Comment: the macro recorder might help you on this - very useful when trying to replicate longer formulas

Comment: `"New to Qualified and" & Range("F3:F100")` Does this return something?

Comment: @Jo.lass can you explain how to do that?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns No, this is to create a variable, which I have used in the 'If Function'

Comment: If I reply your code like you've posted, I get an error on line `str1 = "New to Qualified and" & Range("F3:F100")` Are you sure there is nothing missing? Because normally that kind of lines are for creating arrays, but using `Variants`, not `Strings`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might look more complicated at first but this is a "more VBA way" to do it. Doing this in VBA you will need a loop, since you can't just copy down the cells like you can in the worksheet. I usually avoid using `WorksheetFunction`. The following code will put all your values into an array and produce an array `arrJ` filled with the results. You do not need to approach this with arrays, but I would recommend using the `If - ElseIf - Else` structure I provided below, since it makes the code much easier to read, understand and modify.

```
Sub CC()

Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
str1 = "New to Qualified and "
str2 = "TCV Change and "

Dim arrB As Variant, arrF As Variant, arrG As Variant, arrH As Variant 'rename these to describe your data instead of columns
arrB = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B100").Value2
arrF = ActiveSheet.Range("F3:F100").Value2
arrG = ActiveSheet.Range("G3:G100").Value2
arrH = ActiveSheet.Range("H3:H100").Value2

Dim rngJ As Range
Set rngJ = ActiveSheet.Range("J3:J100")

Dim strResult As String
Dim arrJ As Variant
ReDim arrJ(LBound(arrB) To UBound(arrB), 1 To 1)

For i = LBound(arrB) To UBound(arrB)
    If arrB(i, 1) = vbNullString Then
        strResult = vbNullString 
    Else
        If arrG(i, 1) = "NA" And arrF(i, 1) = "Qualified" Then
            strResult = "New to Qualified"
        ElseIf arrG(i, 1) = "NA" And arrF(i, 1) <> "Qualified" Then
            strResult = str1 & arrF(i, 1)
        ElseIf arrG(i, 1) <> "NA" And arrF(i, 1) = "Qualified" Then
            If arrH(i, 1) <> arrG(i, 1) Then
                strResult = "TCV Change"
            Else
                strResult = "Same"
            End If
        ElseIf arrG(i, 1) <> "NA" And arrF(i, 1) <> "Qualified" Then
            If arrH(i, 1) = "NA" Then
                strResult = "TCV Change"
            ElseIf arrH(i, 1) <> arrG(i, 1) Then
                strResult = str2 & arrF(i, 1)
            Else
                strResult = arrF(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    arrJ(i, 1) = strResult
Next i

rngJ.Value2 = arrJ

End Sub
```

Also, I find it useful to learn to do this kind of stuff in VBA the "proper way" (although I'm sure there are more elegant ways to solve this). This is in the long run of course, for a quick solution you might use something similiar to the code you posted.

A somewhat easier, and slower, way would be the following code. Again, please note that you will need to use a loop to achieve what you're trying to do.

```
Sub CC()

Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
str1 = "New to Qualified and "
str2 = "TCV Change and "

Dim i As Long
Dim strB As String, strF As String, strG As String, strH As String 'rename to describe your data
Dim strResult As String

For i = 3 To 100
    With ActiveSheet
        strB = .Cells(i, 2).Value2
        strF = .Cells(i, 6).Value2
        strG = .Cells(i, 7).Value2
        strH = .Cells(i, 8).Value2
    End With

    If strB = vbNullString Then
        strResult = vbNullString
    Else
        If strG = "NA" And strF = "Qualified" Then
            strResult = "New to Qualified"
        ElseIf strG = "NA" And strF <> "Qualified" Then
            strResult = str1 & strF
        ElseIf strG <> "NA" And strF = "Qualified" Then
            If strH <> strG Then
                strResult = "TCV Change"
            Else
                strResult = "Same"
            End If
        ElseIf strG <> "NA" And strF <> "Qualified" Then
            If strH = "NA" Then
                strResult = "TCV Change"
            ElseIf strH <> strG Then
                strResult = str2 & strF
            Else
                strResult = strF
            End If
        End If
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value2 = strResult
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The second code works perfectly. However, the first code throws a Type mismatch error on the "Redim" line. Also, the above code that I posted is more direct and I was hoping it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how exactly it should work with ranges but i tried to fix your code on cell level

try to use this:

```
str1 = "New to Qualified and" & Range("F7")
str2 = "TCV Change and" & Range("F7")
```

...

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Range("J7").Value = _
    IIf(.And(Range("G7") = "NA", Range("F7") = "Qualified"), "New to Qualified", _
    IIf(.And(Range("G7") = "NA", Range("F7") <> "Qualified"), str1, _
    IIf(.And(Range("G7") <> "NA", Range("F7") = "Qualified"), IIf(.And(Range("H7") <> Range("G7")), "TCV Change", "Same"), _
    IIf(.And(Range("G7") <> "NA", Range("F7") <> "Qualified"), IIf(Range("H7") = "NA", "TCV Change", IIf(Range("H7") <> Range("G7"), str2, Range("F7"))), ""))))
End With
```

Comment: You will need to wrap this in a loop to achieve what OP is trying to do